# NSData writeToFile returns NO, but there is not an error

Tags: objective-c, macos

When I try to write binary data in a simple command line tool on a Mac to a file using the following:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *outputPath = [NSString stringWithCString:argv[2] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
BOOL complete = [outputData writeToFile:outputPath options:NSAtomicWrite error:&error];

if (!complete) {
    NSLog(@"Error when writing to output file.");
    NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
}
```

complete is set to `NO`, but `error.description` is `(null)`.

`outputData` is full. `outputData.length` reports `1307520`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `outputPath` valid (non-`nil`)?

Comment: What is the path supposed to be? Does the error object have a code?

Comment: I've tried using many paths, like just `this.bin` or `/Users/georgewhite/this.bin`; both have the same issue.

Comment: @KenThomases `outputPath` is not nil, and is valid.

Comment: Is `error` itself `nil` (as opposed to `error.description`)? You can log it with `%p` rather than `%@` to be sure. If it's not `nil`, try `error.localizedDescription`.